# Git: Checkout all files except one

Tags: git, git-checkout

When I do a git status, I see files like this:

```
modified:  dir/A/file.txt
modified:  dir/B/file.txt
modified:  dir/C/file.txt
modified:  dir/D/file.txt
```

What I want to do is to discard changes to all files EXCEPT for dir/C/file.txt

I want to do something like this:

```
git checkout -- dir/!C/file.txt
```

Answer (score 162, accepted):

```
git add dir/C/file.txt # this file will stay modified and staged
git checkout .
```

If you want to unstage the file after that:

```
git reset
```

Comment: ABSOLUTELY BRILLIANT

Comment: git clean -df - is helpful if you have a dirty folder

Answer (score 0):

There is a secret single line command for it:

```bash
git checkout -- $(git diff --name-only | grep -v "path/to/your/file")
```

For multiple files:

```bash
git checkout -- $(git diff --name-only | grep -E -v "file1|file2|file3")
```