# Is there a way in git to checkout all files except 1 or 2?

Tags: git

Sometimes I find myself in the position where I want to dump everything in my working tree except for 1 or 2 files. Is there an easy way to do this? As it is I've been manually typing git checkout .... for all the files I want to checkout from the index and don't include the files I want to keep but that's pretty laborious.

Another way I could think of doing this would be to stash 1 or 2 files I want to keep, then "checkout ." then restore the stash. Would that be a good way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: Checkout all files except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008025/git-checkout-all-files-except-one)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I want to do the same occasionally and usually go with the following set of commands (*assumes than there is nothing in the index*):

```
git add file-to-preserve-1 file-to-preserve-2
git stash save --keep-index "Changes discarded because ..."
# git stash drop # think twice before running this command
git reset
```

In words:

1. Put files you need to preserve to index.
2. Stash everything (possibly with a meaningful message), but leave index untouched.
3. Drop stashed changes (**only** if you sure they are useless).
4. Reset the index.

---

Another way I can think of (didn't try it actually, the first one works fine for me):

```
git update-index --skip-worktree file-to-preserve-1 file-to-preserve-2
git checkout .
git update-index --no-skip-worktree file-to-preserve-1 file-to-preserve-2
```

Explained:

1. Command git to ignore some files.
2. Checkout everything in the current directory.
3. Tell git to treat files from `1` as usual again.

Comment: This is a good work flow, but personally I skip the `git stash drop` step.  It is surprising how often you find yourself wanting the changes you just dropped; and even more surprising how often that realization comes 2 ms after you press return on the drop!

Comment: @WilliamPursell, you're right, edited a bit. Good thing is that git prints hash of dropped stash on the screen, the most important then is to do not lose this information.

Comment: You can give the stash a useful message, eg. `git stash save --keep-index discard-reason`

Comment: @Useless, good point, edited. I always promise myself to give useful messages to stash items, but end up with tenth of them all named like `WIP on ...` ...