# Restore all files except one folder

Tags: windows, git, git-for-windows

I've cloned [this](https://github.com/mallowigi/iconGenerator) repo, but two of the files have an asterisk `*` in their names which is a disallowed character for Windows filenames. This means the repo clones but fails to checkout. Cloning looks like this:

```powershell
> git clone https://github.com/mallowigi/iconGenerator.git

Cloning into 'iconGenerator'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2592, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2592/2592), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1545/1545), done.
remote: Total 2592 (delta 1232), reused 2383 (delta 1037), pack-reused 0R
Receiving objects: 100% (2592/2592), 14.87 MiB | 7.26 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1232/1232), done.
# hits error here
error: invalid path 'examples/files/*.pyc'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

When I try `git restore --source=HEAD .` I get this error:

```powershell
> git restore --source=HEAD .
error: invalid path 'examples/files/*.pyc'
error: invalid path 'examples/files/*.pyo'
```

I could go through manually and restore all the folders except `examples/files/`, but my question is: Is there a way to do this with one command? Maybe something like:

```powershell
> git restore --source=HEAD . --except=/examples/files/*
```

Comment: what if you try `git add examples/files/* && git checkout HEAD -- . && git reset`? (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008025/git-checkout-all-files-except-one)

Comment: Well waddaya know `git checkout HEAD -- .` did it perfectly! I got so focused on using restore when the answer was so simple ‍♂️ Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [evolutionxbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989920/evolutionxbox)'s comment the solution was just to do

```
git checkout HEAD -- .
```

This de-stages the deletion of all the other files and leaves a `git status` of:

```powershell
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    examples/files/*.pyc
        deleted:    examples/files/*.pyo
```

Comment: Good to know I was helpful!